# Angular 2 child component can't get parent component

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I'm trying to [make a component](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-form-builder-and-validation-management) which will show specific error messages given control input names.
Here are my codes...

register.ts:

```js
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from 'angular2/common';
import {ControlMessages} from './control-msg';
@Component({
    selector: 'registration-form',
    templateUrl: './app/components/registration/registration.html',
    directives: [ControlMessages]
})
```

control-msg.ts:

```js
import {Component, Host} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgFormModel,FORM_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/common';
@Component({
    selector: 'control-messages',
    inputs: ['controlName: control'],
    template: `<div *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">{{errorMessage}}</div>`
})
export class ControlMessages {
    controlName: string;
    constructor( @Host() private _formDir: NgFormModel){/* _formDir doesn't get the parent object! */}

    get errorMessage() {
        // Find the control in the Host (Parent) form
        let c = this._formDir.form.find(this.controlName);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is as you can see the `ControlMessages` can't get the value of my parent `NgFormModel`.

Angular 2 shows me this error,

> EXCEPTION: No provider for NgFormModel! (ControlMessages -> NgFormModel)

If I include the `NgFormModel` as a provider in the ControlMessages it then shows me this error,

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of null in [errorMessage !== null in ControlMessages@0:5]

Note that I have not injected any providers while bootstrapping the app.
I'm using *angular2 beta 12*.

**Edit:**

form template:

```html
<div class="form-group" 
     [class.has-error]="!registerForm.find('username').valid && registerForm.find('username').dirty">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input type=text id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username" 
         [ngFormControl]="registerForm.find('username')">
  <control-messages control="username"></control-messages>
</div>
```

Comment: have you injected `FORM_PROVIDERS` into bootstrap function?

Comment: Can you please add more code (`RegistrationForm` class, templates)

Comment: The ControlMessages component was nested inside a div. That's why it didn't got the parent object.

Answer (score 1):

The ControlMessages component was nested inside a div. That's why it didn't got the parent object.

The form template should be like this:

```html
<form [ngFormModel]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  <div class="form-group" 
       [class.has-error]="!registerForm.find('username').valid && registerForm.find('username').dirty">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type=text id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username" 
           [ngFormControl]="registerForm.find('username')">
  </div>

  <control-messages control="username"></control-messages>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
          [disabled]="!registerForm.find('username').valid">Register</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Hi @anon. Before proceeding and create a new question, I thought I'd try here first: * q1: where do you provide `NgFormModel`? in bootstrap, or in `ControlMessages`, or both? * q2: do you know how to get a *valid* instance of NgFormModel, with a non-null `.form`, when component is nested inside a <div>?